# XML Serializing not adding elements in XML

Tags: c#

I have a c# class which I generated from XSD, I am serializing it, I have scenario that some elements will be added in specific condition, This is my class

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
public partial class MyRequestClass
{
    private string testNOField;
    private string mOBNOField;
    private int sTYPEField;
    private System.DateTime fRMDATEField;
    private System.DateTime tODATEField;
    public string TESTNO
    {
        get
        {
            return this.testNOField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.testNOField = value;
        }
    }

    public string MOBNO
    {
        get
        {
            return this.mOBNOField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.mOBNOField = value;
        }
    }


    public int STYPE
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sTYPEField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.sTYPEField = value;
        }
    }


    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "date")]
    public System.DateTime FROMDATE
    {
        get
        {
            return this.fRMDATEField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.fRMDATEField = value;
        }
    }


    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "date")]
    public System.DateTime TODATE
    {
        get
        {
            return this.tODATEField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.tODATEField = value;
        }
    }

}
```

The properties FromDate and ToDate will be added in specific condition,The problem is when I am providing values to these two properties,it is not adding these in XML,and no error is appearing as well,Although other elements are adding in this case.
This is how I am serializing

```
       string output = string.Empty;
        XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyRequestClass));
        using (StringWriter sww = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww))
                {
                    //  sww.WriteLine(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>");
                    xsSubmit.Serialize(writer , env);
                    output = sww.ToString();
                }
            }

        var doc = XDocument.Parse(output);
        Enumerable<XElement> emptyElements;
        emptyElements = from descendant in doc.Descendants()
                        where descendant.IsEmpty || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(descendant.Value)
                        select descendant;
        emptyElements.Remove();
        doc.Root.RemoveAttributes();
        output = doc.ToString();
```

Second I am serializing this class in two different cases, In one  case MOBNO should appear in XML and in other case it should not appear,what should I do to implement this feature?

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically add/change attribute value, in this situation it will be XmlIgnore (to hide element). Here is the code:

```
 if (yourCondition)
 {
     XmlAttributes myRequestClassPropertyAttributes = new XmlAttributes();
     myRequestClassPropertyAttributes.XmlIgnore = true;

     XmlAttributeOverrides myRequestClassAttributes = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
     myRequestClassAttributes.Add(typeof(MyRequestClass), "MOBNO", myRequestClassPropertyAttributes);

     XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyRequestClass), myRequestClassAttributes);

     using (StringWriter sww = new StringWriter())
     {
          using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww))
          {
               //  sww.WriteLine(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>");
               xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, env);
               output = sww.ToString();
          }
      }
}
```